# Get exception when animate grid width

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have a longlistselector in a pivot page and I want to show a menu by clicking on a button and with animation. I divide the view in tow grid I animated the width of the one which contains the menu. The problem is when the longlistselector contain element which the height is heigher than the emulator i can not show the menu (I got an exception)